# Do .Net Core environment variables effect anything deep in the project?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

Per the [Microsoft Article on enviornment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.2), I am looking to implement environment variables in a .Net Core application.

I'm curious if setting the "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" environment variable has any effects that are not specifically coded in the development source code (i.e. the code that would be checked into a repo such as git)?

In other words, if my appsettings.Development.json, appsettings.Production.json, and appsettings.Testing.json were all exactly the same and none of MY project code did any checks for the environment type, would the app run the same for all 3?

Or do the environment variables affect modules like maybe something down in the "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting" namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not influence anything else, that would be very weird.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.2

It only influences stuff you specified.

Yes it would run the same on all 3.

Comment: Thanks.  It may seem weird... but I come from other frameworks where it does cause effects down the line.  Specifically how Webpack does its work.  I think I talk a little about it in this video: https://youtu.be/862MLQpsBjE?t=106

Comment: I was curious, so i looked it up in the source: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/search?l=C%23&q=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT It only shows up in settings files or tests, so your good

Comment: Thanks.  What about the IHostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment() function.  Doing a search (thanks for that) I see it in all kinds of files: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/search?q=IsDevelopment&unscoped_q=IsDevelopment

Comment: I see most of them are samples or tests. Any thing specific you are looking for?

Comment: Just want to be sure that your answer is correct based on that search as well.  I don't fully understand what I'm looking at yet, so I just wanted you to look at that search as well.

Comment: This answer may no longer be correct, today I've found 9 usages of IsDevelopment outside test, samples and templates in https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/, affecting settings like `ThrowOnBadRequest`, `OptimizationLevel.Debug`, `AddUserSecrets`, `validateScopes`, `showDetailedErrors`, `UseDeveloperExceptionPage` and response headers "DOTNET-MODIFIABLE-ASSEMBLIES" and "ASPNETCORE-BROWSER-TOOLS". E.g: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c85baf8db0c72ae8e68643029d514b2e737c9fae/src/Http/Routing/src/ConfigureRouteHandlerOptions.cs

Comment: @hectorct you are right, this is not the case anymore it adds multi default things that only works on dev in the webhostbuilder